# Is there any deep learning object detection algorithms that can work without bounding boxes annotated data?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision

For example Haar Cascade can be trained using only positive and negative examples, you don't need any bounding box annotations. But it not a deep learning approach.

Another example can be the most straight forward Image recognition model + sliding window. But it is very slow